# Tate cohomology for group algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A=kG$ be a group algebra with a finite group  $G$ and a field $k$.
Let $T^i(M,N)= \underline{Hom_A}(\Omega^i(M),N)$ be the $i$-th Tate cohomology group. Note $T^i(M,N)= Ext_A^i(M,N)$ in case $i \geq 1$.

> Question: Do we have $dim(T^i(M,M)) \geq dim(Ext_A^1(M,M))$?

This is true in case $A$ is representation-finite.

Comment: No, the Quaternion group $Q$ of order 8 has $\dim \hat{H}^1(Q,\mathbb{F}_2) =2$ and $\dim \hat{H}^n(Q,\mathbb{F}_2) =1$ for $n$ a multiple of 4.